# Complete Custom Camera2 example

Tags: android, android-camera

I need to create a custom camera in Android that supports both higher and lower version.I am new to android.I have research a lot I have the code ready for hardware camera i.e. for the api less than 21.But I am finding hard time searching the code that supports camera hardware 2.

Answer (score 1):

The old deprecated camera API still works on Android 21 and above. But you are right, using the new API is preferable, and gives you more options and better performance.

You can start with the official [Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) sample.

Comment: Sir I have refered the example but still require some more links to research more.Please can u give some more example